# How can I choose Sterling element Appium Android mobile test c#?

Tags: c#, appium-android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjYOh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ud0w.jpg)

There are 22 elements in total in the recyclerview. But I can only see 11 of them. When you scroll up the screen, the Sterling option appears. So how can I select Sterling element C# code ?

My Code:

```
IWebElement btnParaBirimiSterlin => 
     driver.FindElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sterlin']");

public void btnParaBirimiSterlinClick()
    {
        TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
        action.Scroll(btnParaBirimiSterlin, 10, 100);
        action.Perform();
    }
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by 'select': do you mean to place focus on the element, to scroll it into view, or to have that element be the selected value?

Comment: @ErikHeemskerk ı cant not click to sterlin element. so ı want to selected value with scrool